# print group type once and all values in shell

Tags: json, group-by, jq

I grouped a curl response by `stickyType` using following command :

`curl <url> | jq 'group_by(.stickyType)'` 
which gave following output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "stickyType": "TypeA",
      "content": "X",
    },
    {
      "stickyType": "TypeA",
      "content": "Y",
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "stickyType": "TypeB",
      "content": "Z",
    }
  ]
]
```

Now I want to print it as:

```
TypeA
1. X
2. Y

TypeB
1. Z
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: numbering is not necessary.

Comment: Could you share the whole json?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sample JSON shown has been corrected, and that you use the -r command-line option:

- Without numbering

```
    .[] | (.[0]|.stickyType), (.[] | .content)
```

- With numbering:

```
    .[] | (.[0]|.stickyType), (range(0;length) as $i | "\($i). \(.[$i].content)")
```

You could, for example, add either of these to your jq pipeline.